# Wikipedia template for a website

Tags: php, html, css, templates, wikipedia

How can I use Wikipedia look and feel in my website? Is there any prepared one like HTML templates which I could use with a little changes or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki it is the open source wiki package that Wikipedia is written on.

Edit: Be aware that this is GPL version 2 code, so you need to follow all licensing rules.